# How to create a bottom comment widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I would like to build a comment widget floating at the bottom of screen. when user tap the input box, a key board pop-up.

Here is the problem. I tried to add a Container inside of a BottomNavigationBar. But when I tap the input box, key board pop-up and covered the entire BottomNavigationBar. SO I have no way to see what I just tapped in the input box.

Here are 2 images to show you the comment widget box I would like to build. And the key point is I don't want keyboard cover the comment widget.

Please help me.

[close key board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0RRx.jpg)

[open key board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXOUG.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets returns ofsets which caused by keyboards. So, you can wrap your BottomNavigationBar into Padding like this:

```
Scaffold(
  bottomNavigationBar: Padding(padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
  child: BottomNavigationBar(
    ...
  )
...
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work best
[Flutter Comment Box](https://pub.dev/packages/comment_box)

```dart
import 'package:comment_box/comment/comment.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestMe extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestMeState createState() => _TestMeState();
}

class _TestMeState extends State<TestMe> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController commentController = TextEditingController();
  List filedata = [
    {
      'name': 'Adeleye Ayodeji',
      'pic': 'https://picsum.photos/300/30',
      'message': 'I love to code'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Biggi Man',
      'pic': 'https://picsum.photos/300/30',
      'message': 'Very cool'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Biggi Man',
      'pic': 'https://picsum.photos/300/30',
      'message': 'Very cool'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Biggi Man',
      'pic': 'https://picsum.photos/300/30',
      'message': 'Very cool'
    },
  ];

  Widget commentChild(data) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2.0, 8.0, 2.0, 0.0),
            child: ListTile(
              leading: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () async {
                  // Display the image in large form.
                  print("Comment Clicked");
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 50.0,
                  width: 50.0,
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50))),
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 50,
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(data[i]['pic'] + "$i")),
                ),
              ),
              title: Text(
                data[i]['name'],
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              subtitle: Text(data[i]['message']),
            ),
          )
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Comment Page"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: CommentBox(
          userImage:
              "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GjRHcaendrf6gU5fPIVd8GIl1OgblrMMvGUoCBj4g=s400",
          child: commentChild(filedata),
          labelText: 'Write a comment...',
          errorText: 'Comment cannot be blank',
          sendButtonMethod: () {
            if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
              print(commentController.text);
              setState(() {
                var value = {
                  'name': 'New User',
                  'pic':
                      'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GjRHcaendrf6gU5fPIVd8GIl1OgblrMMvGUoCBj4g=s400',
                  'message': commentController.text
                };
                filedata.insert(0, value);
              });
              commentController.clear();
              FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
            } else {
              print("Not validated");
            }
          },
          formKey: formKey,
          commentController: commentController,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          sendWidget: Icon(Icons.send_sharp, size: 30, color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```